# Error IF statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I was trying add to the context menu (for directories) the option "Open Sublime Project" and the icon of Sublime Text Editor 2.

Well, the problem is that if I execute the 2 commands, the execution is perfect, but if I execute the script, only is executed the first command.

**Output:**
No errors

```
If ( -NOT( 
            ([bool](New-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\Open Sublime Project\command" -Value "`"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe`" --new-window %1" -Force)) -OR
            ([bool](New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\Open Sublime Project" -Name "Icon" -PropertyType "String" -Value "`"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe`",0" -Force))
         )
    )
{
    Write-Host "Error"
}
Else
{
    Write-Host "No errors"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get-help about_Logical_Operators` :

> The Windows PowerShell logical operators evaluate only the statements 
>   required to determine the truth value of the statement. If the left
>   operand in a statement that contains the and operator is FALSE, the
>   right operand is not evaluated. **If the left operand in a statement
>   that contains  the or statement is TRUE, the right operand is not
>   evaluated.** As a result, you can use these statements in the same way
>   that you would use  the If statement.

You should separate execution from logical evaluation:

```
$val1 = New-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\Open Sublime Project\command" -Value "`"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe`" --new-window %1" -Force)
$val2 = New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\Open Sublime Project" -Name "Icon" -PropertyType "String" -Value "`"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe`",0" -Force
If (-NOT($val1 -and $val2))
{
    Write-Host "Error"
}
Else
{
    Write-Host "No errors"
}
```

Also, I changed `-or` to `-and`, because with or, if one errors and the other one is successful, it will return no errors, which doesn't make sense to me

Comment: I know use the if statement... In addition, the two commands return true.

Comment: No, the one command returns true, the second command is never evaluated because the first command returns true. There is no reason to evaluate both sides of the `-or` if the left side is already true, which is why the right side is never run.. So just change the `-or` to an `-and` to make your code work, although there are a lot better ways to error check in powershell. But like my post reads, if the left side is false the right side will never run in that case

Comment: Um... But the first command (bool) is false because is negated :/

Comment: Idk what that means, but a boolean is not a command, it is an object

Comment: I understand it now... I have to put a -NOT() in ever object (command1, command2), sure?

Comment: But the negation (-NOT()) is before the IF statement. No logic :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52537/discussion-between-user3602030-and-cole9350)